# In Java, how can I represent a 2d coordinate system in a single array?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, 2d, coordinates

With Java there seems to be a major slowdown when using multidimensional arrays:-

```
int[] oneDArray=new int[3000*3000];
int[][] twoDArray=new int[3000][3000];

for(int x=0;x<oneDArray.length;x++){
   oneDArray[x]=x;
}



for(int x=0;x<twoDArray.length;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<twoDArray[0].length;y++){
        twoDArray[x][y]=x;
    }
}
```

The result is: 1d takes 4 ms, and 2d takes 15ms, this is a considerable delay when performing graphic functions.

How can I represent a 2d coordinate with only a single array in Java?

Comment: You could always have an array of Coordinate objects but I doubt that will solve the time delay issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int w = 3000;
int h = 3000;

int[] array = new int[w * h];

/* Here is how to calculate the index for a specific (x, y) */
int index = y * w + x;

array[index] = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks I will test the performance,  is this O(n)  because normally 2d would imply O(n^2)

Comment: The allocation is O(n) in both cases, and accessing an element is O(1) is both cases. But 2D goes slower because the pipeline stalls when it resolves the memory address of the final element.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common to use an one-dimensional array to represent 2D data. For example you could translate the indices like this:

```
1Dindex = xIndex + IMAGE_WIDTH*yIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

For a rectangular array where all the rows are the same length you can simply use the convention that `oneDArray[x*3000 + y]` holds the value at position (x, y) in the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Use 1D array of pair objects `Pair[]`

```
class Pair {
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Use arithmetic transformation between 1D and 2D: E.g you have dimension 100 * 200;

Then `a[i, j] = a[i * 200 + j]`

Answer (score 0):

How about linearizing the array by doing something like mixing the coordinates? All even elements of the array might pertain to the x and the odd elements to y. If you pick them by pairs, it's even easier to write.

Something like this:

```
x = [x1, x2, x3, x4, ..... , x3000] 
y = [y1, y2, y3, y4, ..... , y3000]
```

and replace it with something like:

```
data = [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, ...... , x3000, y3000]
```

you then can select from this all the even elements to get the x and the odd elements to get the y.
One bonus of this is that you can do something like:

```
coord (point in position i) = [data [2i], data[2i+1]]
```

to bring home the coordinates of point i.

Otherwise I absolutely agree to linearize the array by doing first all the xs and then the ys as others have suggested.

Comment: Are you suggesting like a interlacing structure of vertical rows and column data.

Comment: I have tried to explain it better in the edit. Let me know if you require additional info.